# $H^{p,0}$ is isomorphic to the space of holomorphic forms?

Tags: complex-geometry, hodge-theory

In Voisin's "Hodge Theory and Complex Algebraic geometry I" Corollary 7.6:

$\textbf{Corollary 7.6}$ For every $p\leq n$, $H^{p,0}(X)$ is isomorphic to the space of holomorphic forms of degree $p$ on $X$.

In the proof of Corollary 7.6, Proposition 7.5 was cited:

$\textbf{Proposition 7.5}$ Let $X$ be a compact $\mathbf{Kahler}$ manifold. Let $F^pA^k(X)$ be the set of complex differential forms which are sums of form of type $(r,k-r)$ with $r\geq p$ at every point. Then we have $$F^pH^k(X,\mathbf{C})=\frac{\textrm{Ker}(F^pA^k\to F^pA^{k+1})}{\textrm{Im}(F^pA^{k-1}\to F^pA^{k})}$$

I do not understand the logic, isn't that we have $H^{p,q}(X)\cong H^q(X,\Omega^p_X)$ for all complex manifolds? I don't know where I had the wrong understanding.

Comment: And $H^0(X,\Omega^p)$ is, by definition, the space of holomorphic sections of $\Omega^p$.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I don't understand why Voisin proves corollary 7.6 here, since it is already clear without proposition 7.5？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not obvious that $H^{p,0}$(X) is iso to the $H^0(X,Ω^p)$ (except you define it like that :-)). It is called Dolbeault isomorphism. Which is direct corollary of Hodge theorem. This is always true for compact complex manifold, I mean $H^{p,0}$(X) is iso to the $H^0(X,Ω^p)$. and can be generalized to any holomorphic vector bundle. For noncompact complex manifold, Maybe we need forms with compact support, Which I don't know.

Comment: How do you define $H^{p,0}$?

Comment: There are two way to define $H^{p,q}(X)$, one is cohomology of the elliptic complex: $...--->A^{p,q}(X)--->A^{p,q+1}(X)--->A^{p,q+2}(X)--->...$. If you use this one then it is trivial. just buy just use this fine resolution. The other one is to define it as harmonic (p,q) forms. then it is not trivial. It is Hodge theorem.  I read Voisin for the variation of hodge structures and period mapping part. I guess she define it in second way.